# Nested fieldsets in django admin page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Trying to understand Django Admin a bit better, but facing a problem when placing nested fieldsets in django admin

I want to group my model fields as shown in below image.

I tried using this code, but no success.

```
    class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fieldsets = (
                     ("Main Info", {'fields': ("user", "website")}),
                     ("Phones", {'fields': (
                          ("Primary", {'fields': (("primary_phone_country", "primary_phone_area", "primary_phone_number"),)}),
                          ("Secondary", {'fields': (("secondary_phone_country", "secondary_phone_area", "secondary_phone_number"),)}),
    )}),
)

    admin.site.register(Contact, ContactAdmin)
```

[image]

Any Solutions to solve the above issue?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand this [Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10590) correctly, nested fieldsets are not supported. Although the ticket is 4 years old, it was updated 9 months ago, plus there is no reference to nested fieldsets in the Django documentation.

Having said that, the ticket includes a patch to implement that functionality. Have you tried using it?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.4, and the patch which specified in ticket is not running. Its FAILED.